# Spring Integration 4 - How to set a Gateway's replyTimeout value dynamically?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

My Gateway looks like this ...

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "startChannel", replyTimeout = 1000L)
    ListenableFuture<Boolean> myFlow();
}
```

I use an `application.yml` file to define some properties which I use throughout my application.  One of those is a `timeout` value.

I would like to make `MyGateway`'s `replyTimeout` parameter configurable.

Could someone suggest how I can do that?

Note that `MyGateway` is an Interface so I cannot use `@PostConstruct` or `@Autowired` (as I understand it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an open JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3615.

But I have an workaround for you:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MessagingGateway
public @interface MyMessagingGateway {

    String defaultReplyTimeout() default "" + Long.MIN_VALUE;

}
```

And use this annotation like:

```
@MyMessagingGateway(defaultReplyTimeout = "${reply.timeout}")
public interface MyGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "startChannel")
    ListenableFuture<Boolean> myFlow();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Artem!  That appears to have had the effect that I was looking for.  Now I just need to learn how to tell Spring Integration to interrupt the threads that I now consider to have timed out.